# Replace to the similar data source for a bunch of Tableau Workbooks easily

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have 2 snowflake data sources - both having the same tables, same schema, but different data. Just the server name and data are different, the rest are all the same.

I need to migrate my tableau workbooks (almost 11 workbooks using different tables from snowflake) from one snowflake server data to the other.

Typically, I need to replace my data to point to another similar data source. The manual process is really time-consuming.

Is there any automated process/tool you people are aware of? Any help here is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [document api](https://www.tableau.com/developer/tools/document-api) will allow you to change limited connection information, but does include the server name.  You'll need to download your workbook, make the changes with the API, and republish (so twb without extracts will be fastest).